# display if the numbers are consecutive for upto 3 positions exactly in pandas

Tags: python

I have a df "Index_label", which has only one column(name: column1) which contain numbers.

if we have consecutive position ==3. i would want it as out put

column1

25

26------------consecutive upto 2 positions

110

111

112

113---------------------consecutive upto 4 positions

455

456

457---------------------consecutive upto 3 positions

desired o/p:

110

111

112

455

456

457

Comment: would you not want 113 to appear as her is the consecutive 3rd to 111, 112, 113?

Comment: No, if you are considering 0th position. also there is 110,111,112 only 3 numbers.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please go through all these links: [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [how to good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code (assuming you get the numbers as an iterable of some kind):

```
def getConsecutive(numbers):
  consecutive = []                                 # all 3-consecutive numbers
  sub_series = []                                  # current sub-series of consecutive numbers

  for number in numbers:

    if len(sub_series) == 0:                       # if the current sub-series is empty
      sub_series.append(number)                    # add the current number to it
    else:
      prev = sub_series[-1]         
      if number != prev+1:                         # if the current number is not consecutive
        if len(sub_series) >=3:                    # if there are at least 3 numbers in the sub_series
           consecutive.extend(sub_series[0:3])     # add the first 3 of the sub-series
        sub_series.clear()                         # clear the sub-series
      sub_series.append(number)                    # add the current number 

  if len(sub_series) >=3:                          # check if a 3-consecutive sub series is found
    consecutive.extend(sub_series[0:3])            # add it in

  return consecutive


numbers1 = [25,26,110,111,112,113,455,456,457]
numbers2 = [110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117]
print(getConsecutive(numbers1))         # output = [110, 111, 112, 455, 456, 457]
print(getConsecutive(numbers2))         # output = [110, 111, 112]
```

Comment: input:
25
26
110
111
112
113
114
444
445
446
447

desired op:
110
111
112
444
445
446

basically i want to display only 3 numbers and even if we have consecutive numbers to it i would like to ignore them. i just want 3 numbers and omit the rest of consecutive numbers

Comment: how is your desired output different from the output of the code above?

Comment: it is omitting the 3rd number say we have 110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119
i'm getting 110, 111, 112, 114, 115, 116, 118, 119
so here we are just skipping 113 and 117

Comment: fyi, before this, to fetched only consecutive numbers by using the below code.

Index_label[Index_label.column1.groupby([Index_label.column1.diff().ne(1).cumsum()]).transform('count').ne(1)]

Answer (score 0):

This works (I think?), using a `while` loop and jumping up the count when a consecutive series is found:

```
def three_in_a_row(array):
    output=[]
    c = 0  
    while c < len(array)-2: 
        if (array[c] + 1 == array[c+1]) and (array[c] + 2 == array[c+2]): 
            output += [array[c],array[c+1],array[c+2]] 
            d = 1
            while (array[c] + d == array[c+d]):
                d+=1
                if (d+c) >= len(array):
                    break
            c += d
        else:
            c+=1
    return output

print(three_in_a_row([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
print(three_in_a_row([1,2,3,7,8,9]))
print(three_in_a_row([1,8,9,4,2,4,5,6,7,8]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]
[4, 5, 6]
```

Fun exercise!